# How to encode and decode string to like "\x70\x61\x75\x6c" this in python

Tags: python, string, encode

i am having some keys to send to a server and wanted it encoded.The best was to do it is make the string like ("\x70 \x61 \x75 \x6c") and it and decode it in server.But here i donot know to to convert p a u l (decoded from ("\x70 \x61 \x75 \x6c")) this to string.

*i want to do Like :- paul encrypt to   ("\x70 \x61 \x75 \x6c") and  ("\x70 \x61 \x75 \x6c") decrypt to paul.Thats all.*

Comment: Are you attempting to base64 encode the string?

Comment: Yeah!!!But i want the encrypted output like  ("\x70 \x61 \x75 \x6c") this.Please any solution ?

Comment: So do you want to encrypt output or base64 encode the string? They are different problems.

Comment: i want to do Like :- paul encrypt to   ("\x70 \x61 \x75 \x6c") and  ("\x70 \x61 \x75 \x6c") decrypt to paul.Thats all.

Comment: That isn't an encoding. `"\x70 \x61 \x75 \x6c"` **does not contain** backslashes or `x`s or hex digits. It **means the exact same thing as** `'p a u l'`, which is why if you type `"\x70 \x61 \x75 \x6c"` at the REPL, it will tell you `'p a u l'` back. If you want to make a string that actually contains all those symbols, you certainly can; but it's redundant and not useful - all you seem to want is the hex digits.

Comment: Even then, the best way to solve your problem depends on *why you want to do this* (in particular, you should *not* expect *any* method along these lines to provide **any security at all**).

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you need, ideally as valid, correct Python literals? The string ``"\x70 \x61 \x75 \x6c"`` is *exactly equal the same value* as the string ``"p a u l"``. Are you sure your input is not already in its desired form? Do you need to encode/decode *bytes* perhaps?

Comment: Additionally: `base64` refers to a *very specific* encoding scheme, which is *not this one*. I have removed the tag.

Comment: I think better is use of hexcode instead of this.  here y code 
@app.get("/userAuth/{authcode}")
async def read_items(authcode:bytes):
    encoded = authcode
    encoded=' '.join(bytearray.fromhex(x[2:]).decode() for x in encoded[2:-2].split(' '))
    print(encoded)
    return __get__Sql__(str(decrypt_message(encoded)))

Comment: @KarlKnechtel can you tell me how to do max security and easy encode with base64 ?Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To encode `p a u l` into `("\x70 \x61 \x75 \x6c")`, you could use:

```
s = 'p a u l'
encoded = '("%s")' % ''.join(['\\x'+c.encode('utf-8').hex() if c != ' ' else c for c in s])
```

to decode:

```
encoded = r'("\x70 \x61 \x75 \x6c")'
' '.join(bytearray.fromhex(x[2:]).decode() for x in encoded[2:-2].split(' '))
```

Comment: Please provide code to decoe it again back to p a u l. Thanks Is it approprieate to use bytearray.fromhex("7061756c").decode() ?

Comment: @BijayaKumar here you are